# Getting org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: HTTP ( 400 ) Bad Request address : whenever my request size is large

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am using IBM Websphere 7. IDE: STS, I have generated SOAP client using axis 2. Please find below the stack trace whenever the request size is large:

*********** TRACE com.ajit.olfm.command.center.web.rest.service.RESTService com.ajit.web.service.client.service.RESTService.java - logRequest method [END] 
[3/27/17 15:00:51:332 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: HTTP ( 400 ) Bad Request address : http://ebsdev3.tal.ajit.com/webservices/SOAProvider/plsql/xxmobl_api_pk/
[3/27/17 15:00:51:332 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:332 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:332 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:332 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:586)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:333 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.doInvoke(AxisInvocationController.java:130)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:333 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.InvocationControllerImpl.invoke(InvocationControllerImpl.java:93)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:333 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:391)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:333 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:208)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:333 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.uploaddocument(Unknown Source)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:333 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ajit.web.service.client.service.UploadDocumentClientServiceImpl.uploadDocument(UploadDocumentClientServiceImpl.java:51)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:333 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:333 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:333 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:333 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:333 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:333 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:333 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:333 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:55)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:334 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:334 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:334 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ajit.dsfj.aspect.IAFPerformanceLogForServiceDAOAspect.performanceLogging(Unknown Source)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:334 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:334 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:334 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:334 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:334 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:334 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:334 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:334 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:334 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:334 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:334 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:334 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.uploadDocument(Unknown Source)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:335 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ajit.olfm.command.center.web.rest.service.UploadFileServlet.doPost(UploadFileServlet.java:188)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:335 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:335 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:335 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:335 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1635)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:335 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:113)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:335 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:335 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:335 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:965)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:336 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:336 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:336 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:336 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:336 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:336 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:336 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:336 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:336 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:336 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:336 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:278)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:336 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:336 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:336 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:336 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:337 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:337 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:337 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:337 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:337 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:337 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:337 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: HTTP ( 400 ) Bad Request address : http://ebsdev3.tal.ajit.com/webservices/SOAProvider/plsql/xxmobl_api_pk/
[3/27/17 15:00:51:338 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.processStatusCode(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:3757)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:338 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.send(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:645)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:338 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPTransportSender.invoke(HTTPTransportSender.java:364)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:338 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:564)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:338 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:401)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:338 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:228)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:338 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:163)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:339 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.controller.impl.AxisInvocationController.execute(AxisInvocationController.java:581)
[3/27/17 15:00:51:339 IST] 00000025 SystemErr     R     ... 59 more

Comment: Please note that the request XML generated gets executed successfully from SOAP UI

Comment: I read on certain .NET forums that it is the problem with MaxBufferPoolSize. However, I am not sure it is applicable in my scenario. If someone know how to tweak this parameter in java. I believe it would be worth a try

Comment: did you find anything ? :)

Comment: Yeah I did. I was using STS to generate SOAP client. When I regenerated it using IBM RAD everything felt in place automatically :)